# Best solution to create a nested WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, nested

I need to create the following table with WPF. Have somebody an idea what’s the best way to do it?

Features of the table are:

- Selection behaviour as in Excel
- The table should be fast to load
- Add parent
- Add child to a parent
- The parent and the child have different columns, if the following object in the list have the same column names, I don’t need to create a new header for it.

[image: exampleTable]

Variants are:

1. One DataGrid with special cell styles
2. DataGrid in DataGrid
3. DataGrid in Grid
4. CustomDataGrid in Grid
5. Third party library

Comment: To 5. You could try DevExpress MasterDetail GridControl

Comment: I've looked at the MasterDetail GridControl. It looks unfortunately not as desired. The view should be quite similar to the image above.

Comment: You will probably need a custom grid because of your headers behavior in the child grids. I don't know of any 3rd party providing you with an option to share parent's headers with children. And, after implementing something like this, I would say it is a nasty business. Could you, instead, host an HTML control there?

Comment: A HTML control is not possible or I don't know how. The whole application is WPF.

Comment: [One of examples](http://galratner.com/blogs/net/archive/2014/01/31/creating-hybrid-html5-and-wpf-applications-with-self-hosted-owin-web-api-signalr-and-awesomium.aspx). You should decide, however, (a) - what technology you feel is more convenient for you and (b) - availability of 3rd party controls for your purpose. I suspect there is a good chance to find something like this for Web. But then, there will be a price for integration too...